# Context syncronization issues with Quartz.NET and Dynamic CRM

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, quartz-scheduler

We have switched from Windows Schedule Tasks to Quartz.NET. For the jobs that use Dynamic CRM SDK client we get credential issues as if they are not correct.

If I run them in console or as a Schedule Task they run as expected.

> 2016-07-11 03:30:00,137 ERROR -
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or
>   incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the
>   inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: ID3242: The security token could
>   not be authenticated or authorized.    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---

I think it has to do with the SyncronizationContext of Quartz. But have no idea how the change them in Quartz.

Below a link to a similar issue with a REST client.

[Authentication failing with multiple threads c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211964/authentication-failing-with-multiple-threads-c-sharp)

Comment: http://sscce.org/ ... you think quartz is broken, show us some code to prove it!

Comment: other jobs with not CRM link do run without any problem

Comment: the security context under which the quartz jobs are running is not correct. How is the application hosted? We will need some more information on the hosting environment / application pools / configuration file etc to try and help you figure out why the quartz jobs have different credentials to your other test case.

Comment: Application is hosted as a ServiceHost. It's derived from ServiceBase. The service is running using a service account IUSR_something. But the CRM uses the credentials that are located in the config file of the application.  <CrmConfiguration Url="https://crm.awebsite.be" Username="sa_xrm_admin" Domain="adomain" Password="apassword" IsAdfs="true"/>

Comment: NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "ReGeneSysManualTaskRunner";

            // set thread pool info
            properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "1";
            properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";

            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            _taskScheduler = sf.GetScheduler();